# Pixel Tracking - for affiliates

Tags: php, affiliate, ecommerce-tracking

I need to add **pixel tracking code** on checkout page which is provided by one of my affiliates.

How should I check whether the sales conversion is because of that particular affiliate?

Should I check URN code?

Please help me to get the procedure for doing this?

Is there any Magento extension for this?

Answer (score 1):

i have not advertising in extension.
visit link frinds:-http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/trackpix-affiliatetraction-tracking-pixel.html

and manual code:-
https://retailerintegration.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ret/Pixel+Integration+with+Magento

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-pixel-for-remarketing.html

It works like charm!

Good luck,
Eduardo